# Unzip Downloaded Zip File From Server in Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have Downloaded Zip file form server and saved it to writable path . Now i want to unzip this file

Comment: Can you be more specific?  I presume you mean unzip the file *programatically*?  Take a look at [libzip](https://nih.at/libzip/) or a c++ wrapper such as [libzippp](https://github.com/ctabin/libzippp).  They should have most of the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: I'm developing a game using Cocos2dx 3.10 , and i downloaded my assets (game Images) from server and saved it to Writable path . Now i want to unzip that folder and access these images in games.